# Swift - EXC_BAD_ACCESS when trying to read dict value as Int

Tags: ios, swift, nsdictionary, exc-bad-access

Assuming I have a dictionary defined like this:

```
let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("books", ofType: "plist")
let dict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path)
let books = dict.objectForKey("Books") as [[String:AnyObject]] 
let rnd = Int(arc4random_uniform((UInt32(books.count))))
let bookData = books[rnd]
```

Why does this work?

```
let author = bookData["author"]! as String
```

But this causes a crash:

```
let chapterNum = bookData["chapterNum"]! as Int //should be 5, for example
```

A log of bookData give this:

```
bookData: [content: whatever, author: John Doe, tags: (
    tagA,
    tagB
), chapterNum: 5]
```

Answer (score 1):

bookData["chapterNum"] is probably String not Int

try

```
let chapterNum = dict["chapterNum"] as? Int
```

and you will get nil if type is not what you expect

If you are getting string from a dict you can first get that string and try to turn it into a Int

```
var chapterNum = 0
if let chapterNumString = dict["chapterNum"] as? String {
    if let chapterNumInt = chapterNumString.toInt()? {
        chapterNum = chapterNumInt
    }
}
```

If you dont want to handle optional int value later in that function call

Comment: Well, it gets past that line now. But then I get EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION when I use chapterNum in a function call: `let test = Test(author: author, chapterNum: chapterNum)` where chapterNum expects an Int.

Comment: `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value.` But I can see in the log that chapterNum is not nil.

Comment: Added another example if you want to make sure you get int value... Here it defaults to zero. IMHO what you should really do is continue using optional int and handle it in called method